# diffeomorphisme-exercice on differential calcul

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ an application defined by $f(x,y)=(x+a\sin y,y+b\sin x)$ with $a$ et $b$ are two positives reel such as $ab<1$.

1- Prouve that $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to f(\mathbb{R^2})$ is an diffeomorphism.

2- Prouve that $f(\mathbb{R^2})=\mathbb{R^2}$.

I really have a difficulties with this two questions and i haven't idea. I need the help to undestand this exercice please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inverse function theorem to show that f is a local diffeomorphism, and then use the result that a bijective local diffeomorphism is a global diffeomorphism.

So you only need to show the map is a bijection.

Comment: Yes i know that we can use for the first question, le inverse function theorem GLOBAL and for this, we prouve that $J(f)\neq 0$. But is it suffisant? And for the question 2), i trid to use the fixed point theorem but i haven't a result. Please can you give a complete solution, or any one can gine me a complete solution for this problem because i will be crazy.

Comment: No, it is not sufficient; think of, e.g., the Real version of $e^z$, but that is why I suggest you use the result that a bijective local diffeomorphism is a global diffeomorphism.

Comment: but how we use this result! i haven't an example for this

Comment: You mean you want a proof, or you want to show f is a bijection?

Comment: Pleae, i hope a proof for question 1) and i try to use the point fixe theorem for the question 2) but i don't know how to choose the function to apply the fixed point theorem and prouve 2).Can you help please.

Comment: I don't see how you can use the fixed point thm here to show map is a bijection; if you tell me, I'l look into it besides, I tried the case a=http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f%28x%2Cy%29%3D%28x%2B%280.5%29siny%2Cy%2Bsinx+%291/2, b=1, and the map is not a surjection:

Comment: So please i hope to show the solution of this exercice, can you help me please

Comment: O.K, I'll work on it.

Comment: can you help me please